# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'then')

Tags: solidity

I am writing a solidity code on sublime text, and I couldn't figure the error solution even though the code is correct.

```
beforeEach(() => {
    //Get a list of all accounts
    web3.eth.getAccounts().then(fetchedAccounts => {
        console.log(fetchedAccounts);
    });

    //Use one of those accounts to deploy
    //the contract
});

describe('Inbox', () => {
    it('deploys a contract', () => {});
});
```

Comment: Undefined errors usually are caused by using a variable before it was assigned a value.